# Is this implementation of the negamax algorithm correct

Tags: algorithm, correctness, minimax

I'm trying to implement the negamax algorithm, and this is how I thought it should be:

```
public Move getBestMove(Board board){
 List<Move> possibleMoves = board.getPossibleMoves();
 Move optimalMove;
 int maxScore;
 foreach(Move move in possibleMoves){
  Board newBoard = board.clone();
  newBoard.makeMove(move);
  int score = negamax(newBoard, DEPTH, Integer.MAX, Integer.MIN, 1);
  if (score > maxScore){
    optimalMove = move;
    maxScore = score;
  }
 }
}
```

And the corresponding negamax function

```
public int negamax(Board board, int depth, int alpha, int beta, int sign){
 if(depth == null || board.getPossibleMovesNumber(colour) == 0){
  return calculateBoardFunction(board);
 }
 else{
  List<Move> possibleMoves = board.getPossibleMoves();
  foreach(Move move in possibleMoves){
   Board newBoard = board.clone();
   newBoard.makeMove(move);
   alpha = Math.max(alpha, -negamax(newBoard, depth-1, -beta, -alpha, -sign);
   if(alpha >= beta){
     break;
   }
  }
 return alpha;
}
```

Yeah I know it's not compiling but I'm just trying to pseudocode it a bit.

**Edit**

The calculateBoardFunction(Board board) will ALWAYS evaluate the board for the color that the best move is calculated for.

Also, i've tried to make it generic, so it works the same for every game (chess, reversi, go) etc... (but that's not part of the question)

Also I used the wikipedia's negamax pseudocode as an example. But using that code I >>think<< I could create the game tree very well, with the correct heuristics values. but the reason I have the code in the `getBestMove` function, is to figure out what move is actually the best.

But im not sure if I can do that.

Comment: The heuristic evaluation functions calculates the value for the colour that's on top of the game tree. According to wikipedia: "What can be confusing for beginners is how the heuristic value of the current node is calculated. In this implementation, the value is always calculated from the point of view of the player running the algorithm because of the color parameter. "

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what that quote from wikipedia means now. It says "it's always calculated from the point of view f the play running the algorithm", so if the top-node of the game tree is white, it will calculate the color for the white player. However the quote also says "because of the color parameter" , which I don't understand really.

Comment: Heheh yeah indeed. But I'm still not sure what you meant :p

Comment: Well you _do have_ the colour parameter already, you're just not passing it to the board evaluation function (yet). Seems more efficient at least than letting it work it out from the tree rootnode everytime

Comment: Are you sure I should pass it to the evaluation function. Because according to wikipedia, I think they mean I should calculate the evaluation function to the point of view that the initial call is done.

Comment: @Timo: how does the evaluator _know_ the point-of-view? I'd personally hardcode the POV and make the negamax compensate for it...

Comment: Ah it's not in the code. But the class that this is in, contains a property that the evaluator can get the color for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more or less right. There is a misprint (`-sign` instead of `-colour`), and you need to clone the board every time through the loop (or use `unmakeMove`, but then you don't need a clone in the first place). But apart from this, the logic looks correct.
In the real world, you would want to sort the moves somehow before trying them out. This can result in a huge speed-up, from all the beta cutoffs.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot. The actual code is a little bit more complicated then this, so I adjusted it a bit. Hence the mistikes (the `-sign` -> `-colour` parameters. And the `clone` outside the loop. 

I find this so difficult to debug, so I'm never really sure if I'm doing it right.